# WinForms: color DataGridView border

Tags: winforms

How can I change the color of a DataGridView border when BorderStyle = FixedSingle?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot change the border color, it is system defined.

Instead you could try turning off the border setting and then placing the DataGridView inside a Panel. Where the DataGridView is set to Dock.Fill and the Panel has a Padding of 1 pixel on all edges. Then setting the background color of the Panel will show as a border around the contained DataGridView.

Answer (score 5):

this.dataGridView1.GridColor = Color.BlueViolet;

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehz9ksfa.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could change the border if you make your own DataGridView and override the OnPaint() method. Be sure to call base.OnPaint(e) before you do your own magic.

Also, you could add a property "GridBorderColor" which set color, your own painting would use.